# PHPUnit testing shell execution

Tags: php, phpunit

I have class responsible for interaction with shell, is there any way I can test functions such as this one with **PHPUnit**?

```
public function runCommand($command, $stdin = null)
{
    $descriptorspec = array(
        array("pipe", "r"), // stdin
        array("pipe", "w"), // stdout
        array("pipe", "w"), // stderr
    );

    $environment = array();

    $proc = proc_open(
        $command,
        $descriptorspec,
        $pipes,
        __DIR__,
        $environment
    );

    if (!is_resource($proc)) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($stdin !== null) {
        fwrite($pipes[0], $stdin);
        fclose($pipes[0]);
    }

    $result = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    if (proc_close($proc) !== 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I do not see any `exec()` command, with will be the one executing the shell command.

Comment: proc_open, doesn't it execute $command in shell?

Comment: @fedorqui `$proc = proc_open(`

Comment: You are right! Excuse me, I did not know this function.

Comment: So what about executing a basic `runCommand("ls -l /tmp")`?

Comment: I suppose you could always test running a `ls` from your method and see whether a string (non empty) is returned...

Comment: I guess I'll have to do it in some similar fashion. I've just came up with a very similar solution to ones you suggested tho it requires more setting up and I have no idea if it has any upsides compared to just running `ls`

Answer (score 3):

Here is what came to my mind just after I posted the question. Since I'm testing on linux, I created a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -ne "exec_works"
```

And just ran it in test:

```
public function testShellExecution()
{
    // root tests directory constant, set in PHPUnit bootstrap file
    $path = TESTDIR . "/Resources/exec_test.sh";

    $this->assertEquals(
        "exec_works",
        $this->shellCommander->runCommand("bash $path")
    );
}
```

The downside is that test like this will only pass under linux environment (I've never used MAC so I don't know if it runs bash scripts), but will surely fail on windows since windows can't run bash scripts natively.

The soultion for this would be to just create executable script for every OS and make test check which OS server uses and run appropriate script.